# Centering content in Foundation 6 Flex Grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, flexbox

I am using the Flex Grid component of Zurb Foundation 6 to create a grid of responsive squares -- and that works beautifully. For the life of me, however, I cannot get the square content centered. I have tried all the usual css tricks: relative/absolute, a nested flex grid, etc. There must be something I am missing -- thanks for your help.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/melton1968/23pzeybr/) (which is the base code without any attempt at centering).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="square small-6 columns">
    ABC
  </div>
  <div class="square small-6 columns">
    DEF
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="square small-6 columns">
    123
  </div>
  <div class="square small-6 columns">
    456
  </div>
</div>

.square {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Are you telling me you use a JS framework for flexbox??
I have just checked the doc http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html
I strongly suggest to learn "raw" flexbox, it's simple enough and it's the layout future.

Comment: On that documentation page, there it is explained, but man, that stuff is kinda more complicated than just using flexbox without help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the life of me, however, I cannot get the square content centered. I have tried all the usual css tricks: relative/absolute, a nested flex grid, etc.

Well, the nested flex grid actually works:

```
.square {
    border: solid blue 1px;
    padding-bottom: 30%;

    display: flex;                /* new */
    justify-content: center;      /* new */
    align-items: center;          /* new */
}
```

It centers the content both vertically and horizontally.

The problem is that the boxes don't have any `height`. There's no space for the content to move vertically. What looks like height is actually `padding`, and that's [outside the content box](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

This is what the layout looks like without the `padding-bottom: 30%`: [DEMO 1](https://jsfiddle.net/23pzeybr/6/)

Then add the nested flex container: [DEMO 2](https://jsfiddle.net/23pzeybr/4/)

Then give the box some height: [DEMO 3](https://jsfiddle.net/23pzeybr/5/)

Per the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp), text goes in the *content box*. The *padding* is generally a content-free zone.

Comment: I need the grid to be responsive and fixing the height (as in DEMO 3) breaks that -- just try expanding and shrinking your browser window for the demo.

Comment: The `padding-bottom: 30%;` in conjunction with the flex grid is what generates the square tiles.

Comment: The fixed height in DEMO 3 was just for illustration purposes. You can still make your grid responsive. Just use viewport units instead of pixels. Revised DEMO 3: https://jsfiddle.net/23pzeybr/7/ (re-size window both vertically and horizontally)

Comment: The `hv`, `hw`, `hmin` and `hmax` units are useful and I crafted a solution around using them with your answer. The drawback to this is that the containers are relative to the viewport and not their parent, so, if you change the gutters, for example, you need to adjust your measurements for the squares.

Comment: If you want the containers to re-size relative to the parent, use percentages  instead of viewport units. Just make sure the parent has a defined height. If the parent height is also a percentage, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: Then adjust sizing for screen size with media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
li {
width:50%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
}
```

That is it, does the trick. Responsive etc.

Link

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/WrMmGe

Comment: I've looked at the `codepen` and I cannot figure out how to integrate the list idea with the grid. Maybe you can show me an example that produces a grid of squares?

Comment: Or, are you saying I should scrap the grid all together and just use lists?

Comment: @RandomBits

Nono, just saying use pure flexbox, no need to use zurb foundation for this. A very simple link like http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/
is all I ever use, try it, it's amazing stuff:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Foundation 6 (with Flex-Grid) only too.
The trick is to attach both `align-spaced` and `align-middle` to the outer `row`.

```
<div class="row align-spaced align-middle">
  <div class="square small-6 row align-center">
    <div class="row align-middle">
      <span>ABC</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="square small-6 row align-center">
    <div class="row align-middle">
      <span>DEF</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-spaced align-middle">
  <div class="square small-6 row align-center">
    <div class="row align-middle">
      <span>123</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="square small-6 row align-center">
    <div class="row align-middle">
      <span>456</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
    .square {
      border: solid blue 1px;
      height: 30vh;
    }

</style>
```

as @michael-b points, the height is important.
Also, you can cut off one div layer if you do not need the blue line.

```
<div class="row align-spaced align-middle" style="height: 100px;">
  <div class="small-6 row align-center">
    <span>...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```